# Getting vc++ 2010 code to compile on ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, ubuntu

i have made a program in vc++ 2010 in win7 but since the submission asked for a unix executable file i got ubuntu and am unable to compile to the program. i give the command:

gcc (filename) -o (submission file)

and i am getting a lot of errors as someone guided me over this site that vc++ code will be entirely supported in ubuntu. Then why is the problem? what is the solution?

also if any ide is needed can i use mu code block of windows for ubuntu as well?

Comment: Post some of the error messages... It's possible that you use features that aren't available on gcc.

Comment: Please paste the error messages here to help you. Secondly, if it is C++, you need to use g++ to compile.

Comment: About Code::Blocks, there is an Ubuntu version, you can get it from Synaptic

Comment: thanks i'm new to ubuntu g++ did the job please add it as an answer so i can officially declare it as an answr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using g++ instead of gcc, also VC++ code may or may not work depending on what the submission is required to do as Windows has different libraries for certain things. Try using g++ instead and edit your errors into the question so we can help better.